# How to show a picture in Python like Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib, octave

This is a `20 x 20` pixels image of a `zero` [image: zero] which image is stored in an array of size 400:

```
X[0,:] = [255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
          255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
          255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
          255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
          255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 254
          254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 254 246
          232 206 206 246 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
          246 182 132 132 132 161 206 232 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
          255 254 206 132 132 132 132 132 132 182 246 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
          255 255 255 254 206 132 132 161 182 161 132 161 232 255 255 255 255 255
          255 255 255 255 255 254 182 132 161 232 246 182 132 161 232 255 255 255
          255 255 255 255 255 255 255 246 182 132 182 246 246 182 132 182 246 255
          255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 246 182 132 182 254 232 161 132 206
          254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 246 182 132 182 246 206 132
          161 232 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 246 182 132 161 206
          161 132 182 246 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 254 206 132
          132 132 132 132 206 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
          232 182 161 132 132 182 232 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
          255 255 254 246 232 206 206 232 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
          255 255 255 255 255 255 254 254 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
          255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
          255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
          255 255 255 255]
```

In Matlab, I can see this picture using this picture `displayData(X(0,:))` command.

Also, using the following commands:

```
% Randomly select 100 data points to display
sel = randperm(size(X, 1));
sel = sel(1:100);
displayData(X(sel, :));
```

I can display different pictures of numbers like:

[image: A lot of pictures]

[image: Machine Learning]

I tried to do the same operation in Python using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(X[0, :])
plt.show()
```

But, it threw this error: `Output: TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

numpy arrays are typically used to hold the data for plotting in matplotlib, so its easiest to read in the greyscale image bytes to a numpy array, tell your numpy array the shape

then there are more settings for plot too

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

zstr = '255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 254 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 254 246 232 206 206 246 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 246 182 132 132 132 161 206 232 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 254 206 132 132 132 132 132 132 182 246 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 254 206 132 132 161 182 161 132 161 232 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 254 182 132 161 232 246 182 132 161 232 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 246 182 132 182 246 246 182 132 182 246 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 246 182 132 182 254 232 161 132 206 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 246 182 132 182 246 206 132 161 232 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 246 182 132 161 206 161 132 182 246 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 254 206 132 132 132 132 132 206 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 232 182 161 132 132 182 232 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 254 246 232 206 206 232 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 254 254 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255'    

z, z.shape = np.array([int(i) for i in zstr.split(' ')]), (20,20)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(z, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
# interpolation=None uses a smoother default interpolatiopn
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To display multiple images in one block (like in your question's example), I use the code below. X4 is the data with images of size 32x32 and I display 10X10 images:

```py
images_100=None
for i in range(10):
  row=None
  for j in range(10):
    if row is not None:
      row=np.concatenate((row,np.reshape(X4[i*j+i+j],(32,32)).T),axis=1)
    else:
      row=np.reshape(X4[i*j+i+j],(32,32)).T
  if images_100 is not None:
    images_100=np.concatenate((images_100,row))
  else:
    images_100=row
plt.imshow(images_100, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

[image]